# Debugging Android Applications Offline

Tags: android, debugging

I am developing a application which uses location services. I need to debug the application using `Log.d()` but that needs the device to be connected to the computer all the way. And that's impossible for me to do. I'll be testing the app for about two hours in travelling. I cannot connect it to PC at that time.

Is there any way to save the log in phone and retrieve it later and can see the LOG data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce your own `Logger` class, a wrapper for `android.util.Log` class, which will redirect output both, to file and console:

```
public class Logger {

    public static PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    private static void init() {
        ...
        // Check if external media is writable
        ...

        if (printWriter == null) {
            try {
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + LOG_DIR);
                dir.mkdirs();
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(dir, LOG_FILE), true));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(Logger.class.getName(), "initExternal() -> IOException", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static synchronized int log(int priority, String tag, String msg) {
        int res = Log.println(priority, tag, msg);

        init(); // May be called just once, depending on your requirements

        printWriter.print(tag + "   ");
        printWriter.print(msg + "\r\n");
        printWriter.flush();
        return res;
    }


    // Duplicates of standard android.util.Log methods:
    public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
        return log(Log.VERBOSE, tag, msg);
    }
    public static int v(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return log(Log.VERBOSE, tag, msg + '\n' + Log.getStackTraceString(tr));
    }
    public static int d(String tag, String msg) {
        return log(Log.DEBUG, tag, msg);
    }
    public static int d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return log(Log.DEBUG, tag, msg + '\n' + Log.getStackTraceString(tr));
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are apps that will grab the last few hundreds of lines of the log and post if via email to whatever email you want to sent to. I have used log collector
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS54dHJhbG9naWMuYW5kcm9pZC5sb2djb2xsZWN0b3IiXQ..
and can recommend it, does the job you need to do for you :D